# What types of DSP jobs are out there besides...?

Tags: discussion

I'm in the middle of looking for a new fulltime gig while consulting in the northeast. Decided not to move west (where there are a ton of jobs) because my extended family is here.

I have found that DSP jobs are divided into two categories:

1. entertaining people
2. or blowing them up

Joking aside, am I missing something here? (maybe ultrasound?) My background is heavily audio slanted but I wouldn't mind trying something else.

Answer (score 4):

The other area is biomedical processing.  I know of no opportunities specifically, but there seems to be a [cluster of biomedical companies around Yale in New Haven, CT in the NE.](http://biomedcareerfair.yale.edu/2015-company-sponsors)

Answer (score 2):

With a background on audio, you can try geophysics. Oil price in not so high. Yet geophysics is slowly beginning to think "big data science", with tons of data to deal with.